# How can I discard some unwanted rows from a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix

```
A= [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16; 17 18 19 20]
```

I want to do some calculation on this matrix. But actually I do not need all the rows. So I have to discard some of the rows from the above matrix before doing a calculation. After discarding 3 rows, we will have a new matrix.

```
B= [1 2 3 4; 9 10 11 12; 17 18 19 20];
```

Now I have to use B to make some other calculations. So how can I discard some of the unwanted rows from a matrix in matlab? Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Try this:** (Use when no. of rows to keep is lesser)

```
%// Input A
A = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16; 17 18 19 20];

%// Rows (1-3,5) you wanted to keep
B = A([1:3, 5],:)
```

**Output:**

```
B =

 1     2     3     4
 5     6     7     8
 9    10    11    12
17    18    19    20
```

**Alternative:** (Use when no. of rows to discard is lesser)

```
%// rows 2 and 3 discarded
A([2,3],:) = [];
```

**Output:**

```
>> A

A =

 1     2     3     4
13    14    15    16
17    18    19    20
```

**Note:** Here (in the alternate method), the output replaces the original `A`. So you need to back up `A` if you need it afterwards. You could do this **before discarding operation** to backup Input matrix

```
%// Input A is backed up in B
B = A;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can select the indices of the rows you want to keep:

```
A([1,3,5],:)

ans =

     1     2     3     4
     9    10    11    12
    17    18    19    20
```